# How to retrieve data from firebase identified by unique key in URL?

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm making a simple blog app with firebase and angular and I need to have an access to any post via URL. For example, blog.com/"unique-post-id". Ids  generate automatically, so I don't understand how to show post this way.

Im using realtime database, the structure is:

```
 posts
 -LpmhCB6MoI1XUoXukew
 text: "first"
 type: 1
 -LpmhMcjP8Sq2CG2aYUk
 text: "second"
 type: 2
 -Lpmrr4P6_DJl1swE9jG
 text: "third"
 type: 3
```

I need that by URL address with unique id it has being showed data of post.

Comment: well, you get the parameter in the url, and in the component you then fetch the post from firebase based on that id parameter.

Comment: Do I need the app-routing for this?

Comment: yep, sounds like you do if you want an url like `blog.com/"unique-post-id"`